# Getting data value from multiple HTML objects in php

Tags: php, html

I have the following HTML data tags:

```
<data value="001">Description</data>
<data value="002">Description</data>
<data value="003">Description</data>
```

The following php code displays the value of only one item but it doesn't work with multiple items:

```
<?php
$myXML = simplexml_load_string($myHTML); //$myHTML contains the data tags.
echo $myXML->attributes()->{'value'};
```

Any ideas how can I display the value for all the data items?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure your example is "Well Formed XML" as required by the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

This comment from the docs might point you in the right direction. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php#122006

It recommends parsing the `$myXML` object with the `children` method.

Comment: @Quentin wrong https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/data

Comment: This because there are multiple `value` and array keys has to be unique, and simplexml_load_string() interprets string into object which is type of array... Still don't know how, but already know why not :)